# How to use php variables as table name to insert records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

i have the table name stored in the `$id` variable.

when i use the variable name with sql query it doesn't work

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO karthick.$id (name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport, cutting, amount, vat) VALUES ('$name', '$tin', '$address', '$product', '$invoice', '$transport', '$cutting', '$amount', '$vat')";
```

when i replace the karthick.$id as karthick.ford it works fine. but i want to use the variable stored in `$id` as my table name. how do i do it.

Edit---------------------------
my php code

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
require 'database.php';
/*$sql = "CREATE TABLE karthick.details (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)";
if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "table created";
}else{
    echo "table not created";
}*/

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["cname"]);
$tin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["tin"]);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["address"]);
$product = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["product"]);
$ddate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["date"]);
$invoice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["invoice"]);
$transport = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["transport"]);
$cutting = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["date"]);
$amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["amount"]);
$vat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["vat"]);
$val = 'karthick'.$id;
echo $val;
$sql = "INSERT INTO $val (name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport, cutting, amount, vat) VALUES ('$name', '$tin', '$address', '$product', '$invoice', '$transport', '$cutting', '$amount', '$vat')";
if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "record inserted";
}else{
    echo "not inserted".$conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `"INSERT INTO karthick".$id."`

Comment: $value = 'karthick'.$id;
$sql = "INSERT INTO $value "

Comment: Have you start session in your page??

Comment: yes i stared my session @Saty

Comment: mysqli_select_db($conn,"database_name");

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
$val = 'karthick'.$id;
$sql = "INSERT INTO $val (name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport, cutting, amount, vat) VALUES ('$name', '$tin', '$address', '$product', '$invoice', '$transport', '$cutting', '$amount', '$vat')";
```

Comment: it returns no database selected

Answer (score 0):

Try using "INSERT INTO karthick.".$id." (name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport

Answer (score 0):

Place the $id in braces{} like karthick.{$id}. The query should be like below.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO karthick.{$id} (name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport, cutting, amount, vat) VALUES ('$name', '$tin', '$address', '$product', '$invoice', '$transport', '$cutting', '$amount', '$vat')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = 'karthick'.$id;
$val = str_replace(" ","",$val);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $val (name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport, cutting, amount, vat) VALUES ('$name', '$tin', '$address', '$product', '$invoice', '$transport', '$cutting', '$amount', '$vat')";
```

Comment: mysqli_select_db($conn,"database_name");

Comment: yes i used `mysqli_select_db($conn,"database_name");` it returns the same error

Comment: this is the error showing `not insertedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''karthick'.ford
(name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport, cutting, a' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO karthick.{$id} (name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport, cutting, amount, vat) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$tin}', '{$address}', '{$product}', '{$invoice}', '{$transport}', '{$cutting}', '{$amount}', '{$vat}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

First method :

Try putting the PHP variables inside curly braces {}

Like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO karthick.{$id} (name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport, cutting, amount, vat) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$tin}', '{$address}', '{$product}', '{$invoice}', '{$transport}', '{$cutting}', '{$amount}', '{$vat}')";
```

Second method :

Use PHP variables outside quotes

Like:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO karthick.".$id." (name, tin, address .....
```

**Update**

try using `` to enclose your table like,

```
$val = "`karthick`.`".$id."`";
```

Comment: i tried your first, second and all answers provided here but it returns the same error. `not insertedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
(name, tin, address, product, invoice, transport, cutting, amount, vat) VAL' at line 1`

Comment: try using `` to enclose your table like, $val = "`karthick`.`".$id."`";

Answer (score 0):

You are creating  karthick.details table instead of karthick.session_id